# How to set up direct access storage between a BL460c Gen8 (Win Server 2012) and D2220sb storage blade

Tags: storage, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have installed a D2220sb storage blade in a c3000 enclosure.  The storage blade's partner device is a HP BL460c Gen 8 Server.  How do I setup a direct access storage?  I have googled and tried to find documentation or steps. I have never installed or configured a storage drive so I do not know the next step.

Comment: Not enough information here. What's not working? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 7):

So storage blades are interesting...

The [HP D2220sb storage blade](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/storage-blades/product-detail.html?oid=5357563#!tab=features) actually creates a PCI connection to the blade server over the enclosure's backplane. The storage blade has an embedded Smart Array P420i RAID controller, so no mezzanine cards are needed in the individual blade server.

Install the BL460c Gen8 server. Place the storage blade in the adjacent slot.

You can configure the storage via the Intelligent Provisioning BIOS Menu during the system POST or install the [HP Smart Storage Administrator](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/server-software/product-detail.html?oid=5409020) (HP SSA) in Windows to perform the configuration of the storage array.

The [D2220sb User Manual](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/action.process/public/psi/manualsDisplay/?sp4ts.oid=5357324&javax.portlet.action=true&spf_p.tpst=psiContentDisplay&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&spf_p.prp_psiContentDisplay=wsrp-interactionState=docId%253Demr_na-c03664718%257CdocLocale%253Den_US&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) is also helpful.

- If the D2220sb is installed in an odd-numbered bay, install the partner server blade in the adjacent even-numbered bay to the right.
- If the D2220sb is installed in an even-numbered bay, install the partner server blade in the adjacent odd-numbered bay to the left.